# How make a file a module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want separate this code below in one file, and then call it in other file. This is possible with exports.module, right?

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var configAuth = require('./authentication');

var app = express();

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    console.log('isAuthenticated', req.isAuthenticated());
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.send('not authenticated');
}

passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
        clientID: configAuth.facebook.clientID,
        clientSecret: configAuth.facebook.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: configAuth.facebook.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            return done(null, profile);
        });
    }
));

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        failureRedirect: '/'
    }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('facebook.com/celicoo');
});
```

I don't know how make this call.

For example, i have this code in the authentication.js file, and i want call it in my routes.js file, how can i do that?

Comment: Please explain your problem better. It's not clear to me what exactly you want separate and how you want to use it.

Comment: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your directory structure and such make a new file called index.js and the only line it should have is:

```
module.exports = require('./app/yourapp');
```

where the yourapp is the file that you posted above, put the contents of that file in whatever directory you want. Execute by running 'node index.js'